# c/c++ hackerrank, my code is working but im getting 0,38/10 points(dunno why) code works

Tags: c++, c

So I am doing HackerRank coding challenges and I am begginer in programming.
My code is working fine on visual studio and dev c++, even HackerRank is saying my code is working good. Now I dont want you to tell me what is wrong, just to tell me is there way to do better code(there is probably) and could it be possible to put all in for loot without using if statement.
Here is [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-for-loop).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int i, n;
   for(i=0;i<2;i++){
     scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n==1) {
        printf("one \ntwo \nthree \nfour \nfive \nsix \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==2) {
        printf("two \nthree \nfour \nfive \nsix \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==3) {
        printf("three \nfour \nfive \nsix \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==4) {
        printf("four \nfive \nsix \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==5) {
        printf("five \nsix \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==6) {
        printf("six \nseven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==7) {
        printf("seven \neight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==8) {
        printf("eight \nnine \neven \nodd");
    }
    else if(n==9){
        printf("nine \neven \nodd");
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. You need to read two integers, and print the result for all integers in between (bounds inclusive).

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into the question.

Comment: *Hint:* the question especially provides information about the `for` loop. This is not to read two integers, but to iterate over the numbers.

Comment: @CommuSoft ohh, thanks!! So it would be for(i=a-1;i<b+1;i++) ??

Comment: @panda: not `a-1` and you can replace `<b+1` with `<= b`

Comment: @CommuSoft ok then, but how will i "conver" 8 into eight, 9 into nine??
if a-1=8-1=7 wouldt it print eight, nine... and for a=8 will print nine... ?

Comment: You can use a sequence of `if` statements as you did in your code or `switch-case` statements...

Comment: @panda: perhaps worth mentioning: you can use `if` statements in a `for` loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will not *fully* answer the question, but give *enough* hints to solve it.

You probably misread the specifications of the question: you are given two numbers *a* and *b* and you need to write down something about **all** numbers between *a* and *b* (bounds inclusive).

## Reading input

Since you need to iterate over all numbers between *a* and *b*, one better first reads these numbers:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
```

## Iterating over the numbers

Next you have to use a `for` loop to iterate over the numbers *n* between *a* and *b*. For each number you have to do something:

```
for(int n = <lower>; n <= <upper>; n++) {
    //do something
}
```

## Action for every *n*

As is specified in the question, for each of these numbers, you need to write down something. If the numbers is between `1` and `9` (inclusive), you need to print the English equivalent. A long sequence of `if(x == val)` statements can be replaced by a `switch`-`case` statement:

```
switch(n) {
    case 1 :
        //do something for 1
        break;
    case 2 :
        //do something for 2
        break;
    //...
    case 9 :
        //do something for 9
        break;
    default :
        //do something if the above didn't match
        break;
}
```

If the number is less than `1` or greater than `9`. The program will execute the `default` case. In that case, you need to check whether the number is even, or odd and print this. You can do this using an `if` statement:

```
if((n&0x01) == 0x00) {
    //n is even, do something
} else {
    //n is odd, do something
}
```

By combining the above patterns, you can construct a program that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, got it when u said It is between a and b, got max points! :) Thanks alot! used my if statement, but needed to fix it a little bit :D

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *itself[] = { 
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "even", "odd"
    };
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    for(int n=a; n<=b; ++n){
        if(1 <= n && n <= 9)
            puts(itself[n]);
        else if(9 < n)
            puts(itself[ 10 + (n & 1)]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reply, but I did it this way. My is way longer, I should fix that. 
BTW. Can me/You remove answers and keep CommuSoft-s one because people are going to do this challenges so they don't just copy/paste.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b, n;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    for (n=a;n<=b;n++){

    if(n==1) {
        printf("one\n");
    }
    else if(n==2) {
        printf("two\n");
    }
    else if(n==3) {
        printf("three\n");
    }
    else if(n==4) {
        printf("four\n");
    }
    else if(n==5) {
        printf("five\n");
    }
    else if(n==6) {
        printf("six\n");
    }
    else if(n==7) {
        printf("seven\n");
    }
    else if(n==8) {
        printf("eight\n");
    }
    else if(n==9){
        printf("nine\n");
    }
    if(n>9){
        if(n%2==0){
            printf("even\n");
        }
    else{
            printf("odd\n");
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```